# R: Using summarise_all(funs(sum)) after spread returns 0 even when NAs removed

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm encountering a sum issue where

```
    spread(FUND, PTD_BALANCE, fill = 0) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

incorrectly returns 0s for all the values in certain columns. This occurs even when I allow NAs in the spread and remove them in summarise. The spread pulls 25 variables from the original 4 columns. Below are a few methods I've already attempted to no avail:

```
Budget_FY11_FY18 <- read.csv("FY_8yr_Adopted_Fund_Clean.csv",
                             colClasses = c(rep("factor",6), "double"))

MBudget_Mvar <- Budget_FY11_FY18 %>%
        select(BUDGET_NAME, PERIOD_NAME, FUND, PTD_BALANCE) %>%
        unite("FY_Month", BUDGET_NAME, PERIOD_NAME, remove = TRUE) %>%
        group_by(FY_Month) %>%
        mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
        spread(FUND, PTD_BALANCE, fill = 0) %>%
        summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

The `dput` `head` for `Budget_FY11_FY18` is (certain labels removed):

```
dput(head(Budget_FY11_FY18))

structure(list(BUDGET_NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("FY11 ADOPTED", "FY12 ADOPTED", "FY13 ADOPTED", 
"FY14 ADOPTED", "FY15 ADOPTED", "FY16 ADOPTED", "FY17 ADOPTED", 
"FY18 ADOPTED"), class = "factor"), PERIOD_NUM = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), FUND = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c(), class = "factor"), 
    SERVICE_CENTER = structure(c(223L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 
    223L), .Label = c(), class = "factor"), ACCOUNT = structure(c(3L, 
    5L, 359L, 202L, 203L, 371L), .Label = c(), class = "factor"), 
    PERIOD_NAME = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("April", 
    "August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
    "March", "May", "November", "October", "September"), class = "factor"), 
    PTD_BALANCE = c(-21895250, -650000, -435042, -4300000, -322908, 
    -513417)), .Names = c("BUDGET_NAME", "PERIOD_NUM", "FUND", 
"SERVICE_CENTER", "ACCOUNT", "PERIOD_NAME", "PTD_BALANCE"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Though I have also attempted reading the non-numeric columns in as `character`, resulting in the following `dput`:

```
> dput(head(Budget_FY11_FY18))

structure(list(BUDGET_NAME = c("FY11 ADOPTED", "FY11 ADOPTED", 
"FY11 ADOPTED", "FY11 ADOPTED", "FY11 ADOPTED", "FY11 ADOPTED"
), PERIOD_NUM = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), FUND = c("General Fund", 
"General Fund", "General Fund", "General Fund", "General Fund", 
"General Fund"), SERVICE_CENTER = c("Unallocated", "Unallocated", 
"Unallocated", "Unallocated", "Unallocated", "Unallocated"), 
    ACCOUNT = c("Ad Valorem Tax - Current", "Ad Valorem Tax Prior", 
    "PILOT's", "In Lieu Of Taxes-Utils", "In Lieu Of Taxes-Sewer", 
    "Property Taxes Interest & Penalty"), PERIOD_NAME = c("July", 
    "July", "July", "July", "July", "July"), PTD_BALANCE = c(-21895250, 
    -650000, -435042, -4300000, -322908, -513417)), .Names = c("BUDGET_NAME", 
"PERIOD_NUM", "FUND", "SERVICE_CENTER", "ACCOUNT", "PERIOD_NAME", 
"PTD_BALANCE"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

At present I have the following packages loaded:

```
 [1] gmp_0.5-13.1        xts_0.10-1          MTS_0.33            zoo_1.8-1          
 [5] tseries_0.10-42     forecast_8.2        gridExtra_2.3       magrittr_1.5       
 [9] readr_1.1.1         ggplot2_2.2.1       bindrcpp_0.2        data.table_1.10.4-3
[13] stringr_1.2.0       tidyr_0.7.2         dplyr_0.7.4
```

I have tried various methods of isolation.

Additional background: I'm trying to spread and sum a dataset with ~420k observations in preparation for analysis as a **multivariate time series**. The data are of numeric class and range from 54 million to -200 million. The reason for the sign changes is that the dataset represents a budget.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share `QBudget`? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I'm struggling to get a concise reproducible example, and the data itself is likely too cumbersome to be worth your time, though I don't mind writing/linking it if necessary. I've added some basic information about the data to my post, and will say that all columns created by spread are numeric. Let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Instead of `head(QBudget)`, use `dput(head(QBudget))` then add the output to your question

Comment: Updated. I removed some of the labels for conciseness. Thank you.

Comment: I get error with `Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor` based on your `dput` output

Comment: I get same error as @akrun when Viewing  dput. My understanding is that QBudget was the result of spread(FUND, PTD_BALANCE, fill = 0) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum)). Because the dput is missing factor labels my guess is that FUND might be inconsistently structured OR while you say all columns are numeric, there are factors in Qbudget which suggests the values were strings or treated as strings due to invalid numeric OR perhaps your original creation of FUND should not convert strings to factors.

Comment: It looks like it's time for me to inspect how I built `QBudget`. I don't expect anyone to to my debugging for me, but if anyone is interested, here's how it came about: Used `rbind` to combine budget reports from Oracle. Used a `for` loop to replace `FUND` code with descriptions. `else` was used instead of `else if` to assign `FUND` label `Unknown`, so it was not explicitly defined. Wrote to .csv and used VBA code for all other code/description replacement.

Comment: So I cleared my environment, created a new script just for this operation/got rid of about 500 lines of code, re-read in the .csv specifying `colClasses`, and am still left scratching my head. I've updated/simplified the question to reflect the latest - what is above is literally all of the code in the script. Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

I originally perceived the issue to be similar to those described in previously answered questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068734/r-collapse-multiple-rows-into-1-row-same-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777972/r-collapse-rows-and-sum-the-values-in-the-column).

Despite the `Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor` discrepancies correctly noted by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) and [Tung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786542/tung), it turned out that upon further review of my raw data, the original code was actually returning the proper values, though obviously the use of the code could create problems elsewhere.

For my purposes, the flaw in methods was one of linear algebra and model selection that occurred further downstream. The matrix resulting from operations described in the question was exactly singular.

My assumption that the issue stemmed from reshaping and summing was incorrect.

Any ensuing discussion is likely best placed on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), or re-framed as a question about the occurrence of malformed factors.

This question and its responses/"answer" should be deleted if it is determined they provide no value to the community.